# Java code for finding non-null values in a column

Tags: java, count, null

I'm using an ETL program called Talend to process an input file, and at the end of the process I have an automatic email component that will send statistical information about the process to my clients. I want to tell them how many people in their file were flagged as "Lenders" and how many were flagged as "Correspondents", which are listed in two separate columns that are created as a result of a CASE statement. In order to represent those figures, I need to perform a count of all non-null values in those columns.

Is it possible to do this using `java`?

Comment: I am sure you can, could you post some code to show your attempt at solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is:

Yes.

try using the following comparison to determine if a value is non-null

```
myVariable != null
```

this returns a `boolean` (`true` or `false`) value and can be used like:

```
int count = 0;

for(Column column : columns){
    if(column != null && column.getValue() != null){
        count++;
    }
}
```